# Monotouch Error: The apple Iphone SDK s not installed

Tags: xamarin.ios

I am finding this error after i installed Xcode 4.6.2. I used to work with Monotouch and Xcode 4.3 and i was able to build monotouch applications.

When i upgraded Xcode to version 4.6.2 I am unable to build the application in Monotouch. I am getting the error Apple Iphone SDK is not installed. Also when i check the version information in Monodevelop i am getting Apple Developer Tools:(Not Found).

In preferences when i check the SDK locations it is displaying SDK is found in default location. I dont know what the issue is.

Comment: Do you [google](http://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/comment/10620/#Comment_10620)? It sounds like a compatibility issue fixed in an update.

Comment: Thanks, Couldn find this yesterday

Answer (score 0):

You can change the iPhone sdk location to your new xcode location in the options of your monotouch project.

Answer (score 0):

What is the version from MonoTouch / Xamarin.iOS? Are the Xcode command line tools installed?

[image: XCode preferences]